# How do I simplify this css with sass?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have a `css` file which I want to simplify it with `sass`, some snippet is as follow:

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    height: 30px !important;
}
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 30px !important;
}
.slick-prev:before {
    content: "\f104" !important;
    font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
}
.slick-next:before {
    content: "\f105" !important;
    font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
}
```

so, the difference is only different in `content: "\f104"`, so I tried to simplify it:

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    height: 30px !important;

    &:before {
        color: #fff important;
        font-size: 30px !important;

        // how can I write here?
    }
}
```

How can I judge the parent is `.slick-next:before` or `.slick-prev:before`?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I judge the parent is `.slick-next:before` or `.slick-prev:before`?

You can't.

This is as far as you can simplify it:

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    height: 30px !important;

    &:before {
        color: #fff !important;
        font-size: 30px !important;
        font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
    }
}
.slick-prev:before {
    content: "\f104" !important;
}
.slick-next:before {
    content: "\f105" !important;
}
```